# Отображение Activity Indicator при нажатии на Tab Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Доброго времени суток. Задача стоит следующая: отобразить Activity Indicator при нажатии на Tab Bar и переходе между привязанными View (проще: имеется, допустим, 3 Tab к каждому из которых соответсвует своё View). Каким образом и как будет правильно осуществить подобное?

Comment: а что именно не получается? отлвить переход или отобразить индикатор?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо назначить себя делегатом для таббар контроллера

```
tabBar.delegate = self;
```

Объявить индикатор переменной инстанса (чтобы иметь референс на нее, когда надо убрать индикатор)

```
@property UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
```

инплементировать метод этого самого делегата

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.indicator.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.indicator startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
}
```

и когда надо остановить просто перестать анимировать (при том, что `hidesWhenStopped = YES`)

```
[self.indicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: Спасибо. C тем, как собственно, нарисовать индикатор я разобрался (пробовал использовать библиотеку MBProgressHUD). Однако столкнулся с проблеммой вызова индикатора и его остановки. "Старт" индикатора я положил в метод didSelectItem (как результат, при нажатии на любой из Tab`ов появляется индикатор), однако, не понимаю куда следует положить "Окончание", ибо после вызова индикатора он бесконечно остаётся на View.

Comment: зависит от кондиции. ну там например, если надо его через 3 секунды убрать или когда какая то загрузка закончится

Comment: добавил в ответ